# Rails requires RubyGems >= 0.9.4. Please install RubyGems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rubygems

I'm deploying to Ubuntu slice on slicehost, using Rails 2.1.0 (from `gem`)

If I try `mongrel_rails` start or script/server I get this error:

```
 Rails requires RubyGems >= 0.9.4. Please install RubyGems
```

When I type `gem -v` I have version `1.2.0` installed. Any quick tips on what to look at to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just finally found [this answer](http://www.shorepound.net/wpblog/?p=65)... I was missing a gem, and thrown off by bad error message from Rails...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reinstalling RubyGems? I had a pretty similar error message until I reuninstalled and for some reason, it installed into a different directory and then the problem went away.